# Open HTML document via tcl passing an argument

Tags: html, tcl

I'm writing an offline manual for some of my tcl macro. All macro are collected in a GUI (we call this as main GUI) with many button as macro are, plus a button that call the manual. In addition, every macro has its dedicated tk GUI. In tk GUI there is an help button that call this manual for this current macro. 
The entire work is organized in this way:

1. There is an home folder that contains many subdir as number of macro
2. In home dir there is the `index.html` page of manual
3. In each subdir there is manual page for that macro called man.html

The `index.html` will be something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#" id="macro1" onclick="myFunction('macro1')">macro 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="macro2" onclick="myFunction('macro2')">macro 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="macro3" onclick="myFunction('macro3')">macro 3</a>
</div>
<iframe id="page" src="man_general.html" ></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(macro) {
        document.getElementById("page").setAttribute("src", macro+"/man.html");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I open the manual page via tcl using command `exec {*}[auto_execok start] "index.html"` (I'm working on Windows enviroment). All system work fine if I call manual from button in main GUI.
Now I would like open the same `index.html` page from the macro dedicated GUI, that shows directly that section of manual. I would like do something like `exec {*}[auto_execok start] "index.html"+parameter` the browser recognized this parameter and perform immediatly the js function to display required page. All system works without using web server. I hope that my problem is clear explained.
Is it possible to do so? Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: My feeling is that you should use fragment identifier in the URL (the bit after the `#`) to pass that information in. I believe you can use some JS to parse that if it is present and "do the right thing", and constructing the URL on the Tcl side should be easy enough.